# How to determine which files are necessary in /bin, /lib, /var, etc.?

Tags: files, filesystems, memory

I'm currently trying to get an image working for a network boot using somebody else's file contents. The previous images I made keeping all original files present were way too big, so I need to shrink down the size of the necessary directories. Looking through the contents of these directories though, like /bin, /dev, /etc, etc., I really can't tell what's crucial to the system versus what is extra stuff specific to certain programs that were installed (which are not needed on the image). I don't want to delete anything important, though.

The biggest directories by far are /etc, /lib, and /usr, all hundreds of MB larger than the equivalent directories of an image I previously got to work in the past. Because of this, I know that there's a lot of extra stuff in these directories. At the same time, I'm using a different operating system version (SL5 instead of SL4) so I'm not sure about comparing and contrasting those, especially since the filesystems had different things installed on them anyway.

Is there a quicker way to either sort what's needed versus what isn't, or to delete a lot of the extra "crap" files? (E.g. one recommendation was to delete everything labelled as documentation, but that's still not enough.)

Comment: For a long-term project to give you a depth of understanding on this subject, you might like to check out ["Linux From Scratch."](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/)

Comment: Do you have an idea of what functionality you need? DHCP, ssh server, your locally-developed software, compression utilities, X Windows, etc.?

Comment: Your're going about this in precisely the wrong way.  Don't start with a large image and remove files, instead start from a bare-minimum base install (of whatever OS you want to use) and then add only the things you need.

Answer (score 2):

You should not delete files directly from system directories.  Instead you should remove unneeded packages. In this manner, the system will remove unnecessary files and its dependences.

Note: you can remove every file (but not directories) in `/var/cache`. Additionally old logs in `/var/log/` could be removed.  Check about unread system mails (`/var/mail/` or `/var/spool`).

Comment: How would I remove the packages? I'm working with these files before they've been mounted as root and the system/any sort of relevant kernel has actually been booted. I.e. if I uninstall a package, it would be on the OS that's actually running. Would chroot work here?

Also, I just checked /var/cache and the only contents in there are directories (coolkey, fontconfig, foomatic, man, mod_proxy, samba, yum--that's all of them). Can I remove their contents at all? (Also directories from what I can see.)

Comment: I take it "SL5" is Scientific Linux 5, in which case you'd be using `rpm -e` to remove packages. `rpm` supports a `--root` option to handle use-cases similar to yours; it handles everything properly (`chroot` where appropriate etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that you should be removing *packages* (rather than individual *files*), I would first ensure that the filesystem supports the update of access-time when a program is executed, and then check which *packages* have not been used since the last boot-time.  Assuming normal use of your system, that's as good a first guess at unused packages as you'll need.

I've done this before (a moderately complicated script).  That can be done by

- using `find` to look for files in your path (e.g., `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc), which have not been accessed "recently" (since the last reboot)
- for each file in that list, keep track of the corresponding package and the most recently-used file belonging to the package (you can use `rpm -ql` *packagename* to get the list of files).
- review the list of packages versus access dates and present a report of potentially unused packages (and their sizes).

Comment: I don't have packagename installed and not sure if I can install it right now. Is there another way of checking for the second part? I'm also still unsure how I would uninstall packages in general since I haven't actually booted up this system yet... See the comment on the other answer.

Comment: I meant *packagename* for the given package you are examining, and pointed to `rpm` because it provides a way to list the files belonging to the package.